# New to R and need help coding function and understanding errors

Tags: r, function, loops, smoothing

So I'm taking a class for R, and I'm having a really hard time coding basic formulas.

Basically what I'm trying to do is find 3 variables but I keep getting errors. (I've attached a picture for easier presentation)

Note:

d is the number of DOF, d=1,...,20

[image]
and this is my code :

```
set.seed(29)
library(ISLR)
library(splines)


#### ETAPE 1 
x <- runif(1000,min=0,max=10)
lambda=(2*x)+(0.2*x*sin(x))
y <- rpois(1000,lambda)

J <- data.frame(x=x, y=y)
plot(x,y,cex=0.4)


### ETAPE 2 

ajust <- matrix(NA,20,1000)

for(i in (1:20)) {
  smoothing=lm(y~ns(x=x,df=i),data=J)
  ajust[i,]=predict(smoothing)
}

fd=function(d) {return(smoothing[d])}

for(i in (1:20)) {
  lines(x,ajust[i,],col=i)
}

lines(x,lambda,col='black')

for(i in (1:20)) {
  d1<- (1/1000)*sum((y-ajust[i,])**2)
}

### Calcul de D2

Mean=lambda

for (d in (1:20)){
  W=(Mean-fd(x))**2
  d2=sum(W)/1000

}
```

It works up until "calcul de D2" where I get "Non-numeric argument to binary operator " error. And I don't understand how to make it work. I know my question might seem a little bit vague so don't hesitate to let me know if something isn't clear.

Comment: Values are assigned to variables with assignation operator "<-" not equal so it should be:

Mean <- lambda

W <- (Mean ...

d2 <-sum...

In a general way, try to reset your mind from other languages, in R you don't need to iterate on a vector to operate over it.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76902/how-can-i-write-math-formula-in-a-post

Comment: @L.Amigo It's not the assignment operator that's the problem. `=` is interchangable with `<-`. Even `(Mean-fd(x))` returns that error. The problem is that `fd(x)` returns a list when apparently that's not what the equation expects. We don't have information on what `f(d)` should be (it's not defined in the picture or question). So we can't fix this, but that's the bug.

Comment: @Hack-R f(d) is a smoothing function, it's suppose to return a vector of 1000 values because it's a function of xi

Comment: Did you see my answer below from yesterday? Is that what you need?

Comment: @Hack-R Yeah! Thanks :) , Any chance you could help me with D3?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, the answer will be updated shortly.

Comment: @Hack-R Actually , the Y in the formula is defined at the top y~rpoi(1000,lambda)

Comment: @Hack-R Is it normal that d2 and d3 are the exact same value ?

Comment: You're correct that they do have the same value in my code below, which is why I was saying I was unsure of the mapping. I have no idea where these equations are from and some of the terms mentioned were not defined, so I guessed at them per the logic below. You should look at whatever source textbook the screenshot equations are from to compare against the ones explained below. If I guessed wrong we can just change the mapping. Do you have a link to the source? Normally X is the vectorized x (i.e. x of all i's in a vector), but that's the same definition as x in your code. You see?

Comment: I see what you're saying. The equations are from my school project. Basically I had to simulated X and Y , as shown in my code so I could then perform a smoothing by splines with different degrees of freedom d=1,...,20 . fd is the function returning the smoothed values for a corresponding degree of freedom. The next step was to calculate D1,D2,D3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug in the code is that your `fd(x)` function call returns a list. This is, as the error says, not a numeric.

We don't have information on what f(d) should be (it's not defined in the picture or question), but it seems that the solution would be to extract whatever component from `fd(x)` you meant to have subtracted from `Mean`.

For example:

```
for (d in (1:20)){
  W=(Mean-fd(x)$fitted.values)**2
  d2=sum(W)/1000

}
```

**Update**

I saw your followup comment/question regarding "D3" from the equations in the picture. I'm a little unsure because I don't have the textbook/context to be sure of the notation (X isn't formally defined and I also had to take a leap of faith that Y in the picture = `Mean` in the code based on how you used it). This is my best guess, based on that context:

```
# The equation for d3 is the expected value of (Y-fd(X))^2.
#
# I don't know the context of this, but I see the definition of d1 and d2.
#
# D1 = for(i in (1:20)) {
#  d1<- (1/1000)*sum((y-ajust[i,])**2)
# }
d1 # [1] 10.04203
#
# D2 = for (d in (1:20)){
# W=(Mean-fd(x)$fitted.values)**2
# d2=sum(W)/1000
# }
# 
d2 # [1] 0.2024568
#
# Based on that, Y = Mean, y = y, x=x, i=i, N=1000
#                W = (Y - fd(xi))^2
# I presume X = vectorized xi
# 
# So, D3 =


D3 = (Mean  - fd(x)$fitted.values)^2

#Since it's an expected value, I presume we take the mean

D3 = mean(D3)
```

Where I may be guessing wrong there is probably X. X in the pictured equation looks like the vector of all `x`[i]. But each element of `x` is an `x`[i] so `x` is already the vector representation thereof.